# GetInstance and GetValues (Custom Setting)

Tags: custom-field, customsetting

is that possible to send the name of the record stored in a String variable to custom setting.
ex.

```
link test=link.getInstance(strvar);
```

the usual way is to pass the record name
ex:

```
link test=link.getInstance('record name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the input parameter of those methods is a *reference* to a String object. When you declare a literal string (i.e. `'something'`) you are indeed creating a new object, then you could explicitly assign it to a variabile (`String recordName = 'something'`), or pass it directly to a method, it doesn't really matter because that string, that *reference*, will be assigned to the **local** variable (`dataSetName`) defined in the method signature, [`public CustomSetting__c getInstance(String dataSetName)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_System_ListCustomSetting_getInstance) in this case.

Therefore the following lines are valid (you can test them from anonymous window in developer console):

```
String csName = 'something';
CustomSettingType__c testCS = CustomSettingType__c.getInstance(csName);

String cmtName = 'somethingElse';
CustomMedatadaType__mdt testCMT = CustomMedatadaType__mdt.getInstance(cmtName);
```

By the way, please consider using [Custom Metadata](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/it/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types_dec/cmt_overview) over Custom Setting.